# umount keeps deleting the mount point

Tags: linux

After changing to new USB hard drives, the umount command in a script I run keeps deleting the mount point /home2/usb.

```
#!/bin/sh
find /home2/usb/q12*.tibx -mtime +31 -delete >> /var/log/usb.log
umount /home2/usb
cd /
exit 0
```

My work around it for now is to do a mkdir /home2/usb in the mount script. Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: How is the mount point created? If it is from some automount program, they tend to clean after themselves.

Comment: It's a bash script which basically does the following: mount /dev/sdb1 /home2/usb. Umount wasn't removing the mount point before the hard drives were replaced.

Comment: @supmethods umount still doesn't delete directories; that functionality is simply not part of it. That's why Felix asks how exactly the mounting is done, and whether there might be automatism at work.

Comment: It's a surprise to me that the umount command is deleting the mount point. The scripts was never changed and did not do this before. All it is DEV_NAME=\`lsscsi -l | grep -i toshiba | awk '{print $6}'` and mount "$DEV_NAME"1 $MNT_POINT > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Is the mount command in this script run as a normal user? Or as root?

Comment: I'm running the script as root

Comment: Then how is the mount point created? Is there a trap a the beginning of the script that cleans up? Your information is too sparse to give reasonable hints.